# "failed to mount ntfs partition"

Tags: mount

I am trying to mount `/dev/sdb3` at `/media/2T2`, but receive the following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb3 at /media/minty/2T2: Command-line `mount   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "mount" "/media/minty/2T2"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I went back into Windows 10 to make sure it was shut down properly, but still the error persists.

What can I do next to resolve this error?

Comment: What you should do is [edit] your question to add English explanatory text to say what you were doing (or trying to do).  Include information about your computer; for starters, what operating system(s) it is running.

Comment: Can you mount it with `ro` as a test?

Comment: There's also a well established question on AskUbuntu around this issue, you might find an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: It also sounds like you're probably suffering the effects of Windows 10s Fast Startup feature: https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Frank suggested in his comment to you, this sounds like a windows fast startup issue.  It catches the unwary off guard.  Some years back windows quietly enabled this by default.  It leaves the ntfs filesystem in a non clean state after normally shutting down windows, so linux can't mount it.  Start Windows, turn the feature off, then shutdown windows and you can then mount w/ linux.